# Tokenization and decoding

Tags: pandas, utf-8, nltk, token

I am trying to tokenize my data but I am struggling quite a lot. Please note that I am very new to NLP.

This is what my data(called spam) looks like:

```
Out[8]: 
                                            text
0  Free entry in 2 a wkly comp to win FA Cup fina...
1  FreeMsg Hey there darling it's been 3 week's n...
2  WINNER!! As a valued network customer you have...
3  Had your mobile 11 months or more? U R entitle...
4  SIX chances to win CASH! From 100 to 20,000 po...
```

And this is what I have tried so far.

```
def tokenize(text):
    tokens = [token for token in simple_preprocess(text) 
                              if token not in STOPWORDS]
    return [token for token in tokens 
                            if token not in custom_stopwords]
tokenize(spam)
```

When I run this I get the following error:

> TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, DataFrame found

So I tried decoding it like this:

```
open(spam).read().decode('utf-8')
```

But this also yields an error:

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame

So from looking at the the errors I see that the problem is the fact that spam is a data frame but I don't know what to do about it.

I also tried using `the nltk.tokenize()` function but that gave me another error

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: I think this is a Pandas question, because what you need is to find a way to apply the NLTK functions to the individual strings inside the data frame, rather than the entire structure. Consider retagging (you can safely drop `gensim` here, I guess).

Answer (score 0):

You should apply your function to the column:

```
spam["text"].apply(tokenize)
```